# Number of items selected in each section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the following implementation, I could able to keep track of each selected cell's indexPath and total number of item selected entire tableView.

I wonder how could I able to get the number of items selected in each section?

```
- (void)selectedItem: (UITableView *)tableView {
    NSArray <NSIndexPath*> *selectedIndexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexpath in selectedIndexPaths) {
        NSLog(@"Section index : %ld", indexpath.section);
        NSLog(@"Row index : %ld", indexpath.row);
    }
}
```

Here is the printout, you can see that I choose 2 items in section 0, and 1 item in section 1.

```
po [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]
<__NSArrayI 0x1744428b0>(
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2},
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000c00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 6},
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000001000116> {length = 2, path = 1 - 8}
)
```

Comment: I think you need to do it manually from indexpath you got

Comment: could you please illustrate ?

Comment: Either you manage your own list of selection of cell section wise or you need to loop indexPaths  and group it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *selectedRowsInSectionDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray <NSIndexPath*> *selectedIndexPaths = [tableview indexPathsForSelectedRows];
for (NSIndexPath *indexpath in selectedIndexPaths) {
    NSInteger numberOfSelectedRows = [[selectedRowsInSectionDictionary objectForKey: @(indexpath.section)] integerValue];
    numberOfSelectedRows++;
    [selectedRowsInSectionDictionary setObject:@(numberOfSelectedRows) forKey: @(indexpath.section)];
}
```

You will get number of selected rows in a section with section number as a key and number of selected rows on that section as a value in selectedRowsInSectionDictionary dictionary.

Comment: FYI - you can replace `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:numberOfSelectedRows]` with `@(numberOfSelectedRows)`.

Comment: And you don't need to convert the section to string for the key. Use `@(indexpath.section)` as the key. Dictionary keys only need to be strings if you want to write the dictionary to the plist file.

Comment: @rmaddy, is there a way to use one single line code to get the number of selectedItem in each section with  `@count` feature in `valueForKeyPath`. or any better idea?